# Remover índices de Linhas e Colunas no DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyqt-5

Estou aprendendo python e comecei o usar o pyqt5 como interface gráfica e, para forçar o aprendizado, estou fazendo um programinha de sorteio de bolas de concursos. Para análise dos dados estou usando `DataFrame` e adicionando no `QListWidget.listWidget`.
No entanto, quando eu envio os dados para visualização, os índices de Linhas e Colunas vão juntos, conforme imagem abaixo. Alguém conhece uma função no `DataFrame` que não mostre os índices?

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(jogos)

interface.listWidget_2.addItem(temp.to_string())
```

[image: imagem das bolas sorteadas com os índices do DataFrame]

Answer (score 1):

A função procurada é o próprio método [`DataFrame.to_string()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) que já está sendo utilizado.

Único requisito necessário para cumprir a tarefa solicitada é o ajuste de dois parâmetros:

- `header` que determina como escrever os nomes das colunas, deve ser ajustado em `False`.
- `index` que determina como escrever os índices das linhas, deve ser ajustado em `False`.

```py
temp = pd.DataFrame(jogos)

interface.listWidget_2.addItem(temp.to_string(header=False, index=False))
```